# C++ function signature that accepts lvalue, rvalue and rvalue ref

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++17

Assuming I have a function like the following:

```
print_sutff(const std::string stuff) {
    std::cout << stuff;
}
```

I can accept:

```
std::string
std::string&
std::string&&
```

Without any influence on how the function code looks like.

However the function could be called in multiple ways, with which I'd like to achieve the following behavior (or as close to it as possible):

```
auto pass = "a string";
print_sutff(pass);
```

Here the user can't use the &&, I would prefer to & to take priority to lvaue

or:

```
print_sutff("a string");
```

Here the && constructor should be invoked.

So my question is:

Is there any way to make a function accept lvalue, & and && ? And if so, is there any way to prioritize which one is used based on the context where it is called ?

If not, is there any way to make a function accept both & and && ? Which would mean the behavior of which signature is used which is well defined.

Comment: If you are going to just print your object, there is no reason not to simply use `const std::string &`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `const std::string` is probably the type that's the least likely to be what you want. If your function is a sink (takes ownership of your argument, or of a copy of your argument) then you are forcing a copy and making it impossible to move away from that copy (which implies yet another copy later on). If the function isn't a sink, then you are forcing a copy for no benifit.

Comment: Is the spelling error in `print_sutff` deliberate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do this:

```
void print_stuff(std::string const& stuff) {
    std::cout << stuff;
}
```

A `const` lvalue reference can accept either lvalues or rvalues. If you're not modifying the input, that's a good default.

---

[Even better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833691/c-function-signature-that-accepts-lvalue-rvalue-and-rvalue-ref/44833881?noredirect=1#comment76648481_44833881), since we're C++17, prefer:

```
void print_stuff(std::string_view );
```

Comment: We are 17, so `void print_stuff(std::string_view stuff);` :)

Comment: @T.C. Are you sure about this ? Is there a compile optimization that will treat this 100% the same way it treats a const& when it can be a const&, because it seems like a const& is the best thing to have here where possible. It involves no copying, it involves no moving and it has 0 side-effects.

Comment: @Barry you seem to harbor the same view, would you care to explain ? I get that moving is preferred in favor of mutable references and lvalue copy is prefered in favor of mutable reference when an object's size is small and code is non performance critical... but here we have const ref, so why is that bad ? Also why make the value copy mutable when it can be const ?

Comment: @George `string_view` and `string` are not the same thing.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I did not realize you weren't using string but the wonderful abomination that is the referential type to all strings of chracters... I would say its not that relevant to the question, since I just used string as an example, it could have been an array or a vector (will be have array_ref/array_view in the future ) ?... either way, as far as I'm concerned the answer is correct, thank you very much

Comment: Why not just use a universal reference template if we are so concerned about not copying anything? `template <typename T> void print_stuff(T&& stuff) { std::cout << std::forward<T>(stuff); }`  Then passing a `const char*` argument won't result in an extra copy too.